# "EVIL" Camera Capabilities

Tags: mirrorless

What are your initial experiences with EVIL (Electronic Viewfinder, Interchangeable Lens) cameras? Are they easier or harder to work with than traditional SLRs? Any tips/tricks for someone who has worked with SLRs in the past on making the transition?

(for those with appropriate rep, please tag accordingly)

Comment: This question is worded in a very subjective manner, you may want to consider rewording it so that it isn't subjective, or risk it being closed per the FAQ: http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: I agree with Rowland that the current wording is bad. I'd say remove "Are they easier or harder to work with than traditional SLRs?" and expand on wanting advice for those moving from SLRs. If you did that I would say it should stand, but if it is unchanged for a while I'd say close it.

Comment: Maybe you could say in more detail what motivates your questions. How, specifically, do you hope we can help you? e.g., are you considering a specific transition? what kind of photography would you like to do? etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major advantage of an electronic viewfinder is the reduced weight do to the absence of a mirror. As pointed out in another answer, this also affects the size. I have not had experiences with such cameras with interchangeable lenses, but I have had various devices with electronic viewfinders.

The advantages are:

- Reduced weight and size;
- Screen overlays similar to those on compact cameras;
- Bright display despite dark subject;
- Electronic shutter is silent.

The disadvantages are:

- No screen can replicate the infinite resolution of TTL viewfinders;
- Screen preview may be deceiving due to lighting compensation (as is the case on compact cameras);
- Disappearance of the mirror's delightful *click-clack* sound.

Answer (score 4):

I personally have not had experience with a [Mirrorless Interchangeable Lens Camera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EVIL_camera), but it seems like the main draw is the smaller size that is possible. They seem to be taking the place of the [rangefinder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rangefinder_camera) in the digital world.

There are drawbacks, namely the lack of an optical through-the-lens viewfinder, which has always been a draw for some to a DSLR, and the smaller sensor size.  As of yet, there are no full frame "EVIL" cameras.

They are not for everyone, but they will certainly have their place when a smaller form factor is important.

Comment: When is size not important?

Comment: When you not concerned with the size/weight of your equipment. For instance, if I am at home or at a specific event, I would rather have a better camera, but if I am out doing street photography or on a hike I may be concerned with the size.

Comment: The absence of the rangefinder is actually a pretty big deal, I hadn't thought about that. My old Olympus E-10 was an early DSLRs to have live preview, which boasted in doing TTL-focusing. I found it so much more comfortable to use than other models, especially in macro.